# php- list folders according to the content of a file sort.txt contained in each folder

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, file-get-contents

The idea is to have an index page with an automatically generated link to each folder in a certain directory. 
Each of these folders contains a sort.txt containing just a number, and an name.txt containing the name of the link.
I want to use the content of all the sort.txt files to sort the order of the links, and the content of each name.txt to be displayed as the link name.

So far, I have this:

```
<?php
$Mydir = './'; 
$folders = glob($Mydir.'[^EXCLUDE]*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$dir = str_replace($Mydir, '', $dir);

sort($dir);
foreach($folders as $key => $dir) {

$taskSort = file_get_contents($dir. "/sort.txt");
$file = ($dir. "/name.txt");
$f = fopen($file, "r");

if ( $line = fgets($f, 1000)) 
echo   '<p><a href="' . $dir . '">⍆ ' . $line . '</a>' . $taskSort . '
<br />';

}
?>
```

I manage to use name.txt for the link name, but not to sort them according to sort.txt. how do I achieve that $taskSort is used to sort the links? 
Sorry I am not a php professional...
Thanks

Comment: What is inside `count.txt`, `name.txt` and `sort.txt`? Give us more information and elaborate on what you want to do please, I don't really get your goal.

Comment: sorry, count.txt and sort.txt are the same, my mistake. I corrected it and tried to explain it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't know the architecture (how many folders you can iterate) I like to use the recursive directory iterator class. I give you a fast sample. I don't test it so maybe I forget something. I let you add some extra check (eg: file is writable ?).

However, you don't give enough informations about what are inside `sort.txt`. By the way I suggest you one possible way. I fill an array with all links and supposed that your `$taskSort` allow you to sort your array at the end of the iteration.

```
$oIterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator(DIRECTORY_PATH));
$aArrayOfLinks = array();
while($oIterator->valid()) {

    // For each file found
    if( $oIterator->getExtension() == 'txt') {

        // Missing additionnal check here

        $sHandle = fopen($oIterator->getPathName, "r");
        if ( $sLine = fgets($sHandle, 1000))  {
            $sDirectory = basename($_oIterator->getPath())
            // if sort.txt is in the dir path maybe you should add a particular case
            $taskSort = file_get_contents($sDirectory. "/sort.txt");
            $aArrayOfLinks[$taskSort] = '<p><a href="' . $sDirectory . '">⍆ ' . $sLine . '</a>';
        }

        fclose($sHandle);
    }

    // Next occurrence
    $oIterator->next();
}
// sort your $aArrayOfLinks following the content of $taskSort (which I don't know)
```

To help you, the class **RecursiveDirectoryIterator** extends the **[FilesystemIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php)** you can get all his methods.

---

If this sample is to hard/not KISS. You can save all links in an array like the following (update and using your code):

```
if ( $line = fgets($f, 1000)) 
    $aArrayOfLinks[$taskSort] = '<p><a href="' . $dir . '">⍆ ' . $line . '</a>' . $taskSort . ';
```

And then sort the `$aArrayOfLinks` but one more time I don't know what are inside `$taskSort`

### Edit:

Following your comment with what's inside your `sort.txt`. I suggest you to use the `ksort()`. For instance:

```
$array = array(03 => 'value1', 02 => 'value2', 01 => 'value3');
ksort($array);
echo'<pre>';print_r($array);echo'</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => value3
    [2] => value2
    [3] => value1
)
```

Comment: sort.txt just contains a nr. like "./projectx/sort.txt" contains 01, "./projecty/sort.txt" contains 02, etc. corrected it above.

Answer (score 0):

thanks debflav, it took me a while, now it works! this is how it looks now:

```
<?php
$Mydir = './'; ### OR MAKE IT 'yourdirectory/';
$folders = glob($Mydir.'[^EXCLUDE]*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$aArrayOfLinks = array();

foreach($folders as $key => $dir) {

$taskSort = file_get_contents($dir. "/sort.txt");
$file = ($dir. "/name.txt");
$f = fopen($file, "r");  
if ( $line = fgets($f, 1000)) 

$aArrayOfLinks[$taskSort] = '<p><a href="' . $dir . '">⍆ ' . $line . '</a><br />';
}
krsort ($aArrayOfLinks);
foreach ($aArrayOfLinks as $value) {
echo $value;
}
?>
```